# Google V8 Javascript Engine, Ubuntu and PHP - how to get it built and working?

Tags: php, javascript, ubuntu, v8

some help would be much appreciated here.

I am running Ubuntu 10.04, I want to use the [V8 Javacript engine](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php) inside PHP. Has anyone managed to do this yet?

So I installed `libv8-2.0.3`, `libv8-dbg`, `libv8-dev` from the software centre. Then I tried:
`sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.2`. This failed due to (i think) this:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/v8js.cc:220: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Array::Get(unsigned int&)’
```

and

```
/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/v8js.cc:438: error: ‘ContextDisposedNotification’ is not a member of ‘v8::V8’
```

I am assuming it is because the packaged version of libv8 is too old?

I checked out the SVN source (`svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8`) and used `scons` to build it, although it looks like it finished successfully (`ranlib libv8.a; scons: done building targets.`), I have no idea what to do with what has been generated (and what files were built - there only appears to be .o files built in obj/release/).

I am stuck and somewhat confused as to what I need to do. Help please!

Comment: You should definitely not use trunk but try an older release of v8-dev and maybe the v8js pecl binding. Latter gave me an dependency error (ubuntu bundles 5.3.2, but v8js needs 5.3.3 - not sure if that's a plausible requirement).

Comment: Thanks @mario, I did start by upgrading PHP to 5.3.5. Is the v8js pecl binding different to what I was trying with: sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.2. I can try an older version, but am still left with the question of what to do once scons has built libv8, how do I think go about installing it so that I can then install the v8js pecl extension?

Comment: @Mark. I've tried it too now, failed. I used v8 svn `branch/2.5`, which built ok. Then used `phpize` in the v8js pecl directory. Compiling succeeded, but linking did not. No idea what to do about `relocation R_X86_64_32S against 'vtable for v8::ScriptData' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. Maybe try the v8-svn 3.0 branch?

Comment: How did you build the v8 svn branch, did you use scons? I am unsure what is the best way to build it as I had problems with the method stated in build/README.txt although that was with the trunk version. I am now trying with the 3.0 branch...

Comment: There was no README in 2.5, so through trial and error used `scons -d arch=x64`

Comment: Does that then place the library in the correct place on the system? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I have read a lot trying to get this working in the last couple of days but still have a few fundamental grey areas. It builds successfully, then when I try sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.2 it tells me I should reinstall the v8 distribution. Would it work if I downloaded v8js into the v8 folder and then done the phpize, configure and make?

Comment: I'm not really into compiling from source. I just copied the libv8.a into /usr/lib, and the v8*.h into /usr/include. And phpize/configure picked it up. The problem is that libv8 is built as static .a object collection, and it uses the wrong relocation ?? whatever. Or as the error message says, it should be built with `-fpic` somehow (tried hacking that into linking flags, but no joy.)

Comment: Thanks :) I copied the files across but making v8js fails with multiple errors. I copied v8*.h into /usr/include but was I supposed to copy src/*.h as is appears to need (and cannot find) additional header files...

Comment: I've copied only `v8-debug.h  v8.h  v8-profiler.h  v8stdint.h` into /usr/include. The errors you get indicate missing functions. Maybe you should try the 2.5 branch too. At least that compiled.

Comment: This seems to describe your case better: http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=21048 - he also recommended using version 3.0.4; so I wouldn't know what to do else...

Comment: Okay, I'm one step closer towards not succeeding. Now told `scons` tu use `-fPIC -DPIC` for building. Got it to compile *and* link, but `dl("v8js.so")` failed with `undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual`.

Comment: I got excited then! Where is 3.0.4 found? The 3.0 branch of libv8 did compile and now that I have copied the right header files into /usr/include, v8js is looking better, although the error now seems to be with PHP_V8_VERSION. I'm not using 64bit, so can compile with just scons. How do I redeclare PHP_V8_VERSION?

Comment: I think that may be because I am also getting this: "checking for V8 version... NONE"

Comment: Write `#define PHP_V8_VERSION "0.1.2"` in the `config.h` of pecl v8js. The scons compilation leads to the `__cxa_pure_virtual` error for me in any case, but I couldn't get the `gyp` process to result in a coherent `libv8.a` either.

Comment: I couldn't get gyp to generate libv8.a either, that's why I tried scons. Currently there is #define PHP_V8_VERSION "2.0.3" in the v8js-0.1.2/config.h so what now? I think that "checking for V8 version... NONE" implies it cannot find the library (libv8.a)

Comment: After running phpize, ./configure, make in v8js dir I get an error with v8js.cc 'PHP_V8_VERSION' not declared in this scope, when viewing the source I notice that the config.h is not always included: `#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif` so how do I know if `#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H` is true?

Comment: If your config.h defines PHP_V8_VERSION as **"2.0.3"**, then that indicates that there are residues from the previous Ubuntu libv8-dev package.

Comment: Ok, so when I reopened config.h I noticed that `/* */
/* #undef PHP_V8_API_VERSION */` had replaced `#define PHP_V8_VERSION "2.0.3"` so I added it back in, I ran make and all was built!

Comment: If it works, then upload and publish your `v8js.so` somewhere.

Comment: I now have v8js.so in the modules folder under v8js-0.1.2! Thank you so much for your help with this, else I would never have gotten this far! Just to figure out what to do with the .so file, although I think that will be straight forward I hope (place in php extensions folder (found using php function: phpinfo()) and add the line in php.ini)

Comment: So, did you get it to work in the end? Tell me, tell me, tell me :}

Comment: :) ...now about to find out, or try... I added extension=v8js.so into the php.ini, copied the file into /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ (which was what phpinfo() told me was the extension path) and restarted apache. There is nothing listed in phpinfo() for v8 except for _ENV["PWD"] = the path that I downloaded v8js into. Therefore I have a feeling something isn't right, I shall try a test...

Comment: Look into the error.log, or use the CLI version and test with `dl("v8js.so");` instead of php.ini registration.

Comment: Thanks, error.log was the way to go, looks like it doesn't work. Any ideas on this one: `<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/v8js.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/v8js.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPv in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />`

Comment: So something failed with the linking for you too. I guess the `scons` build method is definitely not viable anymore. -- Regardless, I guess you should rather contact the author of v8js now, ask him for advise on your tried procedure or better yet: for a pre-compiled version of v8js.

Comment: I've done exactly as you said. Wondering what the scope of work would be for me (a PHP programmer) to fix this myself... I am going to try compiling with Visual Studio on windows first.

Comment: I managed to build the file successfully in Ubuntu by removing `libv8.a`, making sure that `libv8.so` is in `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/local/lib/`, `/usr/local/v8/` and running `./configure`, `make clean`, `make`. `make test` revealed no errors or warnings! It is now being loaded successfully by PHP! I also created `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/v8.conf` with the contents of: `/usr/local/v8`, `v8.conf` gets loaded by `/etc/ld.so.conf` which has the line `include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`. Now to find somewhere to host the file...

Comment: i installed in debian with: aptitude install php5-dev php-pear; pecl install v8js-0.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Iam using 10.04 Ubuntu, after upgrade gcc and install newest version of libv8 I can install v8js-0.1.3.