# How to install V8js on PHP5.5?

Tags: php, ubuntu, v8, libv8

I want to install the v8js extension for PHP5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 but can't make it working.

When I try to install the v8js extension version 0.2.0 (latest) with PECL, I have this message:

> configure: error: libv8 must be version 3.24.6 or greater
>       ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-v8js' failed

If I try to install an old version, I have a compilation error. This message is very similar to my issue: [Install v8js for php on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982952/install-v8js-for-php-on-ubuntu)

How can I fix this issue?

EDIT: I couldn't install it on Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP5.5, even with a PHP downgrade with PHPbrew to PHP 5.4. However, using Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.4 works great. I didn't try the downgrade from PHP 5.5 to 5.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

in case you can't find `libv8-dev` or `libv8-dbg`, you can find the correct version by run command

```
~$ apt-cache search libv8
libv8-3.14-dbg - V8 JavaScript engine - debugging symbols
libv8-3.14-dev - V8 JavaScript engine - development files for 3.14 branch
libv8-3.14.5 - V8 JavaScript engine - runtime library
libv8-dev - V8 JavaScript engine - development files for latest branch
```

then you can run

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14-dbg g++ cpp
```

then you can try to install v8js via pecl by running

```
~$ sudo pecl install v8js-0.2.0
```

if that command return error like this

```
configure: error: libv8 must be version 3.24.6 or greater
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-v8js' failed
```

you can try to install `v8js-0.1.3` instead by running

```
~$ sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3
```

then edit your `php.ini` to add `v8js` extension

```
~$ echo "extension=v8js.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: Better instructions than the official documentation. Finally installed, cheers. And thanks for covering the errors that encountered from following NETCreator's answer.

Comment: i flow the same way installation was success but when i created index.php file with 
$v8 = new V8Js(); i got 

 got Fatal error: Class 'V8Js' not found .

my v8js.so is located at /usr/lib/201212/v8js.so

and my init is located at /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

can some one guide me on this ???

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your terminal/console
2. `sudo apt-get install libv8-dev libv8-dbg g++ cpp`
3. Make an update `sudo apt-get update`
4. Try `sudo pecl install v8js-0.2.0` (or other version i.e.: `sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3`)
5. Edit your `php.ini` (Check: [Where is my php.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850787/where-is-my-php-ini-file-linux-centos)) file by adding: `extension=v8js.so`.
6. Restart server

If it the extension still doesn't work, try to edit `/etc/php5/conf.d/v8js.ini` and add `extension=v8js.so` and restart server again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These other answers work well and I used v8js-0.1.3 for the past 1.5 years but after needing to upgrade to PHP 7 I needed a better solution as v0.1.3 doesn't compile with PHP 7 (something to do with php_smart_str being renamed to php_smart_string).

After a couple hours of frustrating research and compiling libv8 myself, I didn't want to have to go through this whole process on every server I provisioned.

Anyway, I found [this site](http://oss.io/p/preillyme/v8js) which points you to a [launchpad PPA site](https://launchpad.net/~pinepain/+archive/ubuntu/libv8-5.2) that provides a couple different ubuntu packages with the 5.1 and 5.2 libv8 libraries.

I ran these commands (please don't add repositories of 3rd party devs without understanding the risks).

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pinepain/libv8-5.2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libv8-5.2-dev
sudo pecl install v8js-1.1.0
```

(Thanks @JeyKeu for suggesting to add "apt-get update" to these commands)

I couldn't get v8js-1.3.0 or 1.2.0 to build, but 1.1.0 worked well.  I checked the changelog and found that the latest updates are not necessary in my circumstance anyway.