# PHP Curl - Possible to retrieve Javascript results?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I've done the research and most people seem to say there is no great way for this, but I'd like to ask again.

A 3rd party site is returning a value I need via Javascript. Meaning when I view the source of the page I see lots of JS but in the browser it shows me a simple string. When I use CURL I just get the raw JS.

The string I need is simply something like `4b71ec1a4cc2a95f9dfa1c023ecd74e6` The JS that generates this is about 50 lines long. Any way PHP can process this for me?

The source including the JS is:

```
<!doctype html><html><head></head><body><script>var _0x916d=["\x6C\x20\x42\x28\x78\x2C\x6B\x29\x7B\x70\x20\x61\x3D\x78\x5B\x30\x5D\x2C\x62\x3D\x78\x5B\x31\x5D\x2C\x63\x3D\x78\x5B\x32\x5D\x2C\x64\x3D\x78\x5B\x33\x5D\x3B\x61\x3D\x68\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x30\x5D\x2C\x37\x2C\x2D\x31\x77\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x68\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x5D\x2C\x31\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x76\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x68\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x32\x5D\x2C\x31\x37\x2C\x31\x78\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x68\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x33\x5D\x2C\x32\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x79\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x68\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x34\x5D\x2C\x37\x2C\x2D\x31\x7A\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x68\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x35\x5D\x2C\x31\x32\x2C\x31\x75\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x68\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x36\x5D\x2C\x31\x37\x2C\x2D\x31\x74\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x68\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x37\x5D\x2C\x32\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x6F\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x68\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x38\x5D\x2C\x37\x2C\x31\x6E\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x68\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x39\x5D\x2C\x31\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x70\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x68\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x30\x5D\x2C\x31\x37\x2C\x2D\x31\x71\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x68\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x31\x5D\x2C\x32\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x73\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x68\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x32\x5D\x2C\x37\x2C\x31\x72\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x68\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x33\x5D\x2C\x31\x32\x2C\x2D\x31\x41\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x68\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x34\x5D\x2C\x31\x37\x2C\x2D\x31\x42\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x68\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x35\x5D\x2C\x32\x32\x2C\x31\x4C\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x65\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x5D\x2C\x35\x2C\x2D\x31\x4B\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x65\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x36\x5D\x2C\x39\x2C\x2D\x31\x4D\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x65\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x31\x5D\x2C\x31\x34\x2C\x31\x4E\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x65\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x30\x5D\x2C\x32\x30\x2C\x2D\x31\x4F\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x65\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x35\x5D\x2C\x35\x2C\x2D\x31\x4A\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x65\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x30\x5D\x2C\x39\x2C\x31\x49\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x65\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x35\x5D\x2C\x31\x34\x2C\x2D\x31\x6D\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x65\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x34\x5D\x2C\x32\x30\x2C\x2D\x31\x43\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x65\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x39\x5D\x2C\x35\x2C\x31\x45\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x65\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x34\x5D\x2C\x39\x2C\x2D\x31\x46\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x65\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x33\x5D\x2C\x31\x34\x2C\x2D\x31\x48\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x65\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x38\x5D\x2C\x32\x30\x2C\x31\x47\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x65\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x33\x5D\x2C\x35\x2C\x2D\x31\x50\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x65\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x32\x5D\x2C\x39\x2C\x2D\x31\x69\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x65\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x37\x5D\x2C\x31\x34\x2C\x51\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x65\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x32\x5D\x2C\x32\x30\x2C\x2D\x52\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x67\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x35\x5D\x2C\x34\x2C\x2D\x55\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x67\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x38\x5D\x2C\x31\x31\x2C\x2D\x53\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x67\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x31\x5D\x2C\x31\x36\x2C\x54\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x67\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x34\x5D\x2C\x32\x33\x2C\x2D\x31\x6C\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x67\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x5D\x2C\x34\x2C\x2D\x31\x67\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x67\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x34\x5D\x2C\x31\x31\x2C\x31\x66\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x67\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x37\x5D\x2C\x31\x36\x2C\x2D\x31\x65\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x67\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x30\x5D\x2C\x32\x33\x2C\x2D\x31\x68\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x67\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x33\x5D\x2C\x34\x2C\x56\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x67\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x30\x5D\x2C\x31\x31\x2C\x2D\x31\x6B\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x67\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x33\x5D\x2C\x31\x36\x2C\x2D\x31\x6A\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x67\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x36\x5D\x2C\x32\x33\x2C\x31\x64\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x67\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x39\x5D\x2C\x34\x2C\x2D\x31\x63\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x67\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x32\x5D\x2C\x31\x31\x2C\x2D\x59\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x67\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x35\x5D\x2C\x31\x36\x2C\x58\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x67\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x32\x5D\x2C\x32\x33\x2C\x2D\x57\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x66\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x30\x5D\x2C\x36\x2C\x2D\x5A\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x66\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x37\x5D\x2C\x31\x30\x2C\x31\x38\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x66\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x34\x5D\x2C\x31\x35\x2C\x2D\x31\x62\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x66\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x35\x5D\x2C\x32\x31\x2C\x2D\x31\x61\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x66\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x32\x5D\x2C\x36\x2C\x31\x39\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x66\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x33\x5D\x2C\x31\x30\x2C\x2D\x31\x44\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x66\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x30\x5D\x2C\x31\x35\x2C\x2D\x31\x52\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x66\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x5D\x2C\x32\x31\x2C\x2D\x32\x6A\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x66\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x38\x5D\x2C\x36\x2C\x32\x66\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x66\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x35\x5D\x2C\x31\x30\x2C\x2D\x32\x69\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x66\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x36\x5D\x2C\x31\x35\x2C\x2D\x32\x68\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x66\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x33\x5D\x2C\x32\x31\x2C\x32\x65\x29\x3B\x61\x3D\x66\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x6B\x5B\x34\x5D\x2C\x36\x2C\x2D\x32\x6B\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x66\x28\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x6B\x5B\x31\x31\x5D\x2C\x31\x30\x2C\x2D\x31\x51\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x66\x28\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x6B\x5B\x32\x5D\x2C\x31\x35\x2C\x32\x63\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x66\x28\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x6B\x5B\x39\x5D\x2C\x32\x31\x2C\x2D\x31\x57\x29\x3B\x78\x5B\x30\x5D\x3D\x6F\x28\x61\x2C\x78\x5B\x30\x5D\x29\x3B\x78\x5B\x31\x5D\x3D\x6F\x28\x62\x2C\x78\x5B\x31\x5D\x29\x3B\x78\x5B\x32\x5D\x3D\x6F\x28\x63\x2C\x78\x5B\x32\x5D\x29\x3B\x78\x5B\x33\x5D\x3D\x6F\x28\x64\x2C\x78\x5B\x33\x5D\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x77\x28\x71\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x61\x3D\x6F\x28\x6F\x28\x61\x2C\x71\x29\x2C\x6F\x28\x78\x2C\x74\x29\x29\x3B\x6D\x20\x6F\x28\x28\x61\x3C\x3C\x73\x29\x7C\x28\x61\x3E\x3E\x3E\x28\x31\x58\x2D\x73\x29\x29\x2C\x62\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x68\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x77\x28\x28\x62\x26\x63\x29\x7C\x28\x28\x7E\x62\x29\x26\x64\x29\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x65\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x77\x28\x28\x62\x26\x64\x29\x7C\x28\x63\x26\x28\x7E\x64\x29\x29\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x67\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x77\x28\x62\x5E\x63\x5E\x64\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x66\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x63\x2C\x64\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x77\x28\x63\x5E\x28\x62\x7C\x28\x7E\x64\x29\x29\x2C\x61\x2C\x62\x2C\x78\x2C\x73\x2C\x74\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x4F\x28\x73\x29\x7B\x31\x56\x3D\x27\x27\x3B\x70\x20\x6E\x3D\x73\x2E\x43\x2C\x76\x3D\x5B\x31\x55\x2C\x2D\x32\x64\x2C\x2D\x31\x53\x2C\x31\x54\x5D\x2C\x69\x3B\x75\x28\x69\x3D\x41\x3B\x69\x3C\x3D\x73\x2E\x43\x3B\x69\x2B\x3D\x41\x29\x7B\x42\x28\x76\x2C\x4E\x28\x73\x2E\x4D\x28\x69\x2D\x41\x2C\x69\x29\x29\x29\x7D\x73\x3D\x73\x2E\x4D\x28\x69\x2D\x41\x29\x3B\x70\x20\x72\x3D\x5B\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x2C\x30\x5D\x3B\x75\x28\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x73\x2E\x43\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x72\x5B\x69\x3E\x3E\x32\x5D\x7C\x3D\x73\x2E\x7A\x28\x69\x29\x3C\x3C\x28\x28\x69\x25\x34\x29\x3C\x3C\x33\x29\x3B\x72\x5B\x69\x3E\x3E\x32\x5D\x7C\x3D\x31\x59\x3C\x3C\x28\x28\x69\x25\x34\x29\x3C\x3C\x33\x29\x3B\x4B\x28\x69\x3E\x31\x5A\x29\x7B\x42\x28\x76\x2C\x72\x29\x3B\x75\x28\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x31\x36\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x72\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x30\x7D\x72\x5B\x31\x34\x5D\x3D\x6E\x2A\x38\x3B\x42\x28\x76\x2C\x72\x29\x3B\x6D\x20\x76\x7D\x6C\x20\x4E\x28\x73\x29\x7B\x70\x20\x44\x3D\x5B\x5D\x2C\x69\x3B\x75\x28\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x41\x3B\x69\x2B\x3D\x34\x29\x7B\x44\x5B\x69\x3E\x3E\x32\x5D\x3D\x73\x2E\x7A\x28\x69\x29\x2B\x28\x73\x2E\x7A\x28\x69\x2B\x31\x29\x3C\x3C\x38\x29\x2B\x28\x73\x2E\x7A\x28\x69\x2B\x32\x29\x3C\x3C\x31\x36\x29\x2B\x28\x73\x2E\x7A\x28\x69\x2B\x33\x29\x3C\x3C\x32\x34\x29\x7D\x6D\x20\x44\x7D\x70\x20\x45\x3D\x27\x32\x61\x27\x2E\x32\x62\x28\x27\x27\x29\x3B\x6C\x20\x4A\x28\x6E\x29\x7B\x70\x20\x73\x3D\x27\x27\x2C\x6A\x3D\x30\x3B\x75\x28\x3B\x6A\x3C\x34\x3B\x6A\x2B\x2B\x29\x73\x2B\x3D\x45\x5B\x28\x6E\x3E\x3E\x28\x6A\x2A\x38\x2B\x34\x29\x29\x26\x49\x5D\x2B\x45\x5B\x28\x6E\x3E\x3E\x28\x6A\x2A\x38\x29\x29\x26\x49\x5D\x3B\x6D\x20\x73\x7D\x6C\x20\x4C\x28\x78\x29\x7B\x75\x28\x70\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x78\x2E\x43\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x78\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x4A\x28\x78\x5B\x69\x5D\x29\x3B\x6D\x20\x78\x2E\x32\x39\x28\x27\x27\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x48\x28\x73\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x4C\x28\x4F\x28\x73\x29\x29\x7D\x6C\x20\x6F\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x29\x7B\x6D\x28\x61\x2B\x62\x29\x26\x32\x38\x7D\x4B\x28\x48\x28\x27\x32\x35\x27\x29\x21\x3D\x27\x32\x36\x27\x29\x7B\x6C\x20\x6F\x28\x78\x2C\x79\x29\x7B\x70\x20\x47\x3D\x28\x78\x26\x46\x29\x2B\x28\x79\x26\x46\x29\x2C\x50\x3D\x28\x78\x3E\x3E\x31\x36\x29\x2B\x28\x79\x3E\x3E\x31\x36\x29\x2B\x28\x47\x3E\x3E\x31\x36\x29\x3B\x6D\x28\x50\x3C\x3C\x31\x36\x29\x7C\x28\x47\x26\x46\x29\x7D\x7D\x6C\x20\x73\x28\x73\x29\x7B\x6D\x20\x48\x28\x22\x32\x37\x22\x2B\x73\x2B\x22\x32\x67\x22\x29\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x67\x67\x7C\x69\x69\x7C\x68\x68\x7C\x66\x66\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x33\x32\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x7C\x74\x61\x69\x6C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x63\x6D\x6E\x7C\x7C\x7C\x63\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65\x41\x74\x7C\x36\x34\x7C\x6D\x64\x35\x63\x79\x63\x6C\x65\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x6D\x64\x35\x62\x6C\x6B\x73\x7C\x68\x65\x78\x5F\x63\x68\x72\x7C\x30\x78\x46\x46\x46\x46\x7C\x6C\x73\x77\x7C\x6D\x64\x35\x7C\x30\x78\x30\x46\x7C\x72\x68\x65\x78\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x68\x65\x78\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x6D\x64\x35\x62\x6C\x6B\x7C\x6D\x64\x35\x31\x7C\x6D\x73\x77\x7C\x31\x37\x33\x35\x33\x32\x38\x34\x37\x33\x7C\x31\x39\x32\x36\x36\x30\x37\x37\x33\x34\x7C\x32\x30\x32\x32\x35\x37\x34\x34\x36\x33\x7C\x31\x38\x33\x39\x30\x33\x30\x35\x36\x32\x7C\x33\x37\x38\x35\x35\x38\x7C\x36\x38\x31\x32\x37\x39\x31\x37\x34\x7C\x39\x39\x35\x33\x33\x38\x36\x35\x31\x7C\x35\x33\x30\x37\x34\x32\x35\x32\x30\x7C\x34\x32\x31\x38\x31\x35\x38\x33\x35\x7C\x31\x39\x38\x36\x33\x30\x38\x34\x34\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x31\x31\x32\x36\x38\x39\x31\x34\x31\x35\x7C\x31\x37\x30\x30\x34\x38\x35\x35\x37\x31\x7C\x35\x37\x34\x33\x34\x30\x35\x35\x7C\x31\x34\x31\x36\x33\x35\x34\x39\x30\x35\x7C\x36\x34\x30\x33\x36\x34\x34\x38\x37\x7C\x37\x36\x30\x32\x39\x31\x38\x39\x7C\x31\x35\x35\x34\x39\x37\x36\x33\x32\x7C\x31\x32\x37\x32\x38\x39\x33\x33\x35\x33\x7C\x31\x35\x33\x30\x39\x39\x32\x30\x36\x30\x7C\x31\x30\x39\x34\x37\x33\x30\x36\x34\x30\x7C\x35\x31\x34\x30\x33\x37\x38\x34\x7C\x37\x32\x32\x35\x32\x31\x39\x37\x39\x7C\x33\x35\x38\x35\x33\x37\x32\x32\x32\x7C\x33\x35\x33\x30\x39\x35\x35\x36\x7C\x36\x36\x30\x34\x37\x38\x33\x33\x35\x7C\x31\x37\x37\x30\x30\x33\x35\x34\x31\x36\x7C\x34\x35\x37\x30\x35\x39\x38\x33\x7C\x31\x39\x35\x38\x34\x31\x34\x34\x31\x37\x7C\x34\x32\x30\x36\x33\x7C\x31\x38\x30\x34\x36\x30\x33\x36\x38\x32\x7C\x31\x39\x39\x30\x34\x30\x34\x31\x36\x32\x7C\x31\x34\x37\x33\x32\x33\x31\x33\x34\x31\x7C\x31\x32\x30\x30\x30\x38\x30\x34\x32\x36\x7C\x33\x38\x39\x35\x36\x34\x35\x38\x36\x7C\x36\x38\x30\x38\x37\x36\x39\x33\x36\x7C\x36\x30\x36\x31\x30\x35\x38\x31\x39\x7C\x31\x30\x34\x34\x35\x32\x35\x33\x33\x30\x7C\x31\x37\x36\x34\x31\x38\x38\x39\x37\x7C\x34\x30\x33\x34\x31\x31\x30\x31\x7C\x31\x35\x30\x32\x30\x30\x32\x32\x39\x30\x7C\x34\x30\x35\x35\x33\x37\x38\x34\x38\x7C\x31\x38\x39\x34\x39\x38\x36\x36\x30\x36\x7C\x35\x36\x38\x34\x34\x36\x34\x33\x38\x7C\x31\x30\x31\x39\x38\x30\x33\x36\x39\x30\x7C\x31\x31\x36\x33\x35\x33\x31\x35\x30\x31\x7C\x31\x38\x37\x33\x36\x33\x39\x36\x31\x7C\x33\x38\x30\x31\x36\x30\x38\x33\x7C\x37\x30\x31\x35\x35\x38\x36\x39\x31\x7C\x31\x36\x35\x37\x39\x36\x35\x31\x30\x7C\x31\x32\x33\x36\x35\x33\x35\x33\x32\x39\x7C\x31\x30\x36\x39\x35\x30\x31\x36\x33\x32\x7C\x36\x34\x33\x37\x31\x37\x37\x31\x33\x7C\x33\x37\x33\x38\x39\x37\x33\x30\x32\x7C\x31\x34\x34\x34\x36\x38\x31\x34\x36\x37\x7C\x31\x31\x32\x30\x32\x31\x30\x33\x37\x39\x7C\x31\x30\x35\x31\x35\x32\x33\x7C\x31\x37\x33\x32\x35\x38\x34\x31\x39\x34\x7C\x32\x37\x31\x37\x33\x33\x38\x37\x38\x7C\x31\x37\x33\x32\x35\x38\x34\x31\x39\x33\x7C\x74\x78\x74\x7C\x33\x34\x33\x34\x38\x35\x35\x35\x31\x7C\x33\x32\x7C\x30\x78\x38\x30\x7C\x35\x35\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x7C\x35\x64\x34\x31\x34\x30\x32\x61\x62\x63\x34\x62\x32\x61\x37\x36\x62\x39\x37\x31\x39\x64\x39\x31\x31\x30\x31\x37\x63\x35\x39\x32\x7C\x73\x69\x64\x7C\x30\x78\x46\x46\x46\x46\x46\x46\x46\x46\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x37\x31\x38\x37\x38\x37\x32\x35\x39\x7C\x32\x37\x31\x37\x33\x33\x38\x37\x39\x7C\x31\x33\x30\x39\x31\x35\x31\x36\x34\x39\x7C\x31\x38\x37\x33\x33\x31\x33\x33\x35\x39\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x7C\x31\x35\x36\x30\x31\x39\x38\x33\x38\x30\x7C\x33\x30\x36\x31\x31\x37\x34\x34\x7C\x32\x30\x35\x34\x39\x32\x32\x37\x39\x39\x7C\x31\x34\x35\x35\x32\x33\x30\x37\x30","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function(_0x789dx1,_0x789dx2,_0x789dx3,_0x789dx4,_0x789dx5,_0x789dx6){_0x789dx5=function(_0x789dx3){return (_0x789dx3<_0x789dx2?_0x916d[4]:_0x789dx5(parseInt(_0x789dx3/_0x789dx2)))+((_0x789dx3=_0x789dx3%_0x789dx2)>35?String[_0x916d[5]](_0x789dx3+29):_0x789dx3.toString(36))};if(!_0x916d[4][_0x916d[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0x789dx3--){_0x789dx6[_0x789dx5(_0x789dx3)]=_0x789dx4[_0x789dx3]||_0x789dx5(_0x789dx3)};_0x789dx4=[function(_0x789dx5){return _0x789dx6[_0x789dx5]}];_0x789dx5=function(){return _0x916d[7]};_0x789dx3=1};while(_0x789dx3--){if(_0x789dx4[_0x789dx3]){_0x789dx1=_0x789dx1[_0x916d[6]]( new RegExp(_0x916d[8]+_0x789dx5(_0x789dx3)+_0x916d[8],_0x916d[9]),_0x789dx4[_0x789dx3])}};return _0x789dx1}(_0x916d[0],62,145,_0x916d[3][_0x916d[2]](_0x916d[1]),0,{}));document.cookie="sid1="+s("e39ab29b52f58b01a44d568481b70833")+"; path=/";document.location.reload(true);</script></body></html>
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
//for this sample the $raw is saved in a local file. $raw is obtained by using curl. 
$raw = file_get_contents('raw.txt');

function get_result($raw) {
    $key = str_replace ('document.location.reload(true);','',$raw);
    $key = str_replace('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>', '', $key);
    $key = str_replace('</body></html>', '', $key);

    return $key;
}

$key = get_result($raw);
echo $key;

//this key in this string is hardcoded for sample purposes
echo "<script> document.write(s('e39ab29b52f58b01a44d568481b70833'));</script>";
```

This code is in raw.php. Then in separate file:

```
 $curl = curl_init();
 $curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'raw.php');
 $url_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 $result = curl_exec ($curl);
 echo $result;
```

the results is just the markup not the JS results.

Comment: I have done it, so keep trying.

Comment: Can you share the 50 lines of code?

Comment: You need to show us your `curl` code as well as the page you want information from. You need to setup your `curl` request correctly to get the return value from the script.

Comment: thank you. i have updated the question with the code and JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the JavaScript extension for PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

PECL packages can be a pain to install. This package has to be compiled from the sources before it can be used.

[Installing PHPv8js on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770601/installing-phpv8js-on-ubuntu)

Once you have the extension added you can use it in PHP.

```
<?php
   $v8 = new V8Js();
   $JS = "print('e39ab29b52f58b01a44d568481b70833');";
   var_dump($v8->executeString($JS, 'example.js'));
 ?>
```

There is no `document` or `window` types in the Javascript engine. So your Javascript source might not work anyway. To get around that problem you'll need a more involved solution using a headless browser like http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Thank you. phantomjs along with the PHP plugin at http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/ seem to be the way to go. I was able to successfully retrieve the value I was looking for