# Php: Error installing v8js on laravel homestead ( vagrant ) on ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel-5, vagrant, v8, homestead

Hello i am having trouble installing v8js on laravel homestead ( vagrant )

After looking at these 2 tuts

[1. Install v8js on Linux (works with Homestead)](https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel/blob/master/install_v8js.md#install-v8js-on-linux-works-with-homestead)!

[2. Installing PHPv8js on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655649/3301436)!

I Fired up the below commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install libv8-dev libv8-dbg g++ cpp
$ sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3
```

Also note that i typed `/opt/v8` when it asked me for the installation prefix of libv8

**Edit: As per user(s) request i am posting the error code and removing the screenshots for the same**

Here is my error code

When i run first command i get this error

```
$ sudo apt-get install libv8-dev libv8-dbg g++ cpp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libv8-dbg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libv8-dbg' has no installation candidate
```

When i run 2nd command , it asks me to provide the installation prefix of libv8 ... i type `/opt/v8` and getting the below error

```
$ sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3
downloading v8js-0.1.3.tgz ...
Starting to download v8js-0.1.3.tgz (17,968 bytes)
......done: 17,968 bytes
8 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
Please provide the installation prefix of libv8 [autodetect] : /opt/v8
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3
running: /tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-v8js=/opt/v8
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20151012
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for V8 Javascript Engine... yes, shared
checking for V8 files in default path... found in /usr
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for V8 version... 3.14.5.9
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3/libtool --mode=compile g++  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/v8js -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/v8js -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/v8js/v8js.cc -o v8js.lo
libtool: compile:  g++ -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/v8js -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootlo1BwQ/v8js-0.1.3/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/v8js -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/v8js/v8js.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/v8js.o
/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/v8js.cc:32:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [v8js.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: done ehsan , now i hope it helps!

Comment: The problem you are facing during your make process is because of an unresolved dependency, Check the dependencies of v8js first and try to resolve them.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I've got the same issue when installing v8js on homestead. :(

Comment: nopes .... still waiting for anybodies revert @UmarW

Comment: @Ehsan how do i check that ?

Comment: Its a known bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5177

Answer (score 4):

I've found a fix for this; we should **checkout the version 5.1.99** as the latest v8js build seems broken.

## Background history

A [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5177) has been raised to the v8 team by [stacie](https://github.com/stesie)

Bug *"unicode/uchar.h" not found while building V8 #238* also opened on [Github](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/issues/238)

A [solution log](https://gist.github.com/tiemevanveen/61cc1d5980abcd7f45e3aeb93e8214bf) has been provided by [tiemevanveen](https://github.com/tiemevanveen)

## Current Solution

The commands are as follows:

### Install `build-essential` if you haven't already:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

### Install `libicu-dev` if you haven't already:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
cd /tmp
```

### Install depot_tools first (needed for source checkout)

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

### Download v8

```
fetch v8
cd v8
```

### checkout working version:

```
git checkout 5.1.99
gclient sync
```

### use libicu of operating system

```
export GYP_DEFINES="use_system_icu=1"
```

### Build (with internal snapshots)

```
export GYPFLAGS="-Dv8_use_external_startup_data=0"
```

### Force gyp to use system-wide ld.gold

```
export GYPFLAGS="${GYPFLAGS} -Dlinux_use_bundled_gold=0"
make native library=shared snapshot=on -j8
```

### Install to /usr

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib /usr/include
sudo cp out/native/lib.target/lib*.so /usr/lib/
sudo cp -R include/* /usr/include
```

### ... same for V8 < 5.2.51, libv8_libplatform.a is built in tools/gyp directory

```
echo -e "create /usr/lib/libv8_libplatform.a\naddlib out/native/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a\nsave\nend" | sudo ar -M
```

### Compile php-v8js itself

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js.git
cd v8js
phpize
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Then add extension=v8js.so to your php.ini file.

[Official guide](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/master/README.Linux.md)

Comment: Seems like it worked ( though not sure but seems like :P )

Comment: It should :), this should be marked as accepted for future references until the bug is permanently solved.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while installing v8js on a Ubuntu 16 VM (using vagrant/Homestead). Instead of compiling from source, here's how I solve this issue:

```
 1. sudo apt-get install g++ cpp 
 2. sudo add-apt-repository
 3. sudo apt-get update 
 4. sudo pecl install v8js
 5. sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
```