# php v8js on ubuntu - error v8js class not found

Tags: php

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.6 and successfully installed `v8js-0.1.3` using `sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3`.

I followed this installation process
[Installing PHPv8js on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770601/installing-phpv8js-on-ubuntu).

Which is display when I am using `php -m`.

But when I call new object of `v8js` like `$v8 = V8Js()`.
I get the following error `:- Fatal error:  Class 'V8Js' not found`

Answer (score 1):

V8Js is a PHP7 extension for Google's V8 Javascript engine [V8 Js](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js).

Comment: I have already installed latest node >  7.0 so don't think installation of v8. Means i have to make and sudo make install of V8 JS am i right ?

Comment: The minimum requirement mentioned in the  link is php7. May be because of that  it is not working.